# D Templates: Sort a list of types

Tags: templates, sorting, d

Assume you have a type like the following:

```
struct Value(int v_)
{
  static const v = v_:
}
```

How would you sort a list of these types, assuming an interface something like this:

```
alias Sorted!(Value!(4), Value!(2), Value!(1), Value!(3)) SortedValues;
```

You may use D 2.x features if it makes for a better solution, but please state if you do so.

I'll post my solution in a day or so.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using D 1.0, have a QuickSort!

http://paste.dprogramming.com/dplgp5ic

Comment: I would suggest putting the code some place different since "paste" is not permanent.

Answer (score 1):

By the way unless you have other reasons to do it there is no need to wrap the value in structs as tuples work just fine with values as well.

```
alias Sorted!(4, 2, 1, 3) SortedValues;
```

Comment: True; but I believe that tuples break with aliases.  Using a wrapper struct was just the more general form of the question I could think of.  :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution.  Note quite as cool as FeepingCreature's, but probably simpler to understand; it works by recursively inserting the first type into the rest of the list (after having sorting it).

```
module sort;

/*
 * Tango users substitute "tango.core.Tuple" for "std.typetuple" and "Tuple"
 * for "TypeTuple".
 */

import std.typetuple;

struct Val(string v_)
{
    static const v = v_;
}

template Sorted_impl(T)
{
    alias TypeTuple!(T) Sorted_impl;
}

template Sorted_impl(T, U, V...){

    static if( T.v < U.v )
        alias TypeTuple!(T, U, V) Sorted_impl;

    else
        alias TypeTuple!(U, Sorted_impl!(T, V)) Sorted_impl;
}

template Sorted(T)
{
    alias TypeTuple!(T) Sorted;
}

template Sorted(T, U...)
{
    alias Sorted_impl!(T, Sorted_impl!(U)) Sorted;
}

pragma(msg, Sorted!(Val!("a")).stringof);

pragma(msg, Sorted!(Val!("b"), Val!("a")).stringof);

pragma(msg, Sorted!(
    Val!("d"), Val!("a"), Val!("b"), Val!("c")
).stringof);

static assert( false, "nothing to compile here, move along..." );
```